# testing extensions on Magento enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise, testing

I've written a module for Magento CE, but I have a customer that needs to install it on EE. Is there a way of testing if it works on EE without having to pay the 15,000 fee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mage Testing](http://magetesting.com) service to test your extension using any Magento EE release. You will save $14950 :-)

Another option is to use your customer development server as his EE license should include one.

Comment: Using the customer's development server is the backup plan. I tried using MageTesting, but when I try to access Magento Connect, it says local file doesn't exists. It seems to me like the MageTesting only lets you install the extensions that are uploaded to magento store.

Comment: You can either install extension from Mage Testing extension database or use FTP to upload your extension files. For more information please contact with us via http://magetesting.com/contact-us

Comment: I subscribed to Mage Testing, but after paying the subscription of $50 I still don't have FTP access. Do you know if there is a way to upload my own extension?

Comment: Given Mage testing service is not available too...

Comment: @ArslanTabassum yes, this doesn't work anymore